# react withRouter create a new object for match everytime when mapStateToProps is called

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

not sure if others encounter this issue before:

i am using:
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2"

so I have a component like this,

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps) => {
    // shallow compare each prop and see which one is changed
    console.log(nextProps.history === this.props.history) // true, good
    console.log(nextProps.location === this.props.location) // true, good
    console.log(nextProps.match === this.props.match) // false, what? althought the value inside match is the same? why match is a new object/reference every time?
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  nothing special here, just merge state and ownProps. (Router location/match/history is in ownProps, withRouter inject them in i think)
  at the end of this function i just return the merge of {state, ownProps}
  same issue exists even without my own mapStateToProps
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent))
```

every time there is a state change, mapStateToProps is called. withRouter inject location/match/history is into ownProps. But for some reason 'match' is a new object every time when mapStateToProps is called, and thus it causes unnessarry re-rendering.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a bunch of unnecessary deepEquals on the match prop I'd like to be rid of.

Comment: i used the 3rd param in connect() to filter out the problematic match. connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps), then const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps) => {
  const {match, ...filteredStateProps} = stateProps
  return Object.assign({}, filteredStateProps, dispatchProps)
}

Comment: in another project, we decided not to use withRouter. we have another service to expose route info. dont think using withRouter higher order component is the correct way to go